# Backbone Layout Manager Render list of items

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, backbone-layout-manager

I am new to backbone and backbone layout manager. i am trying to render a list of contacts. here is a snippet of code

```
var ContactListView = Backbone.Layout.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    initialize: function (){
        console.log('ContactListView init');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function (){
        console.log('Rendering all items in the contact list');
        _(this.collection.models).each(function (contact){
            var contactlistitem = new ContactListItemView({model: contact});
            self.$el.append(contactlistitem.el);
        });
    }
});

var ContactListItemView = Backbone.Layout.extend({
    initialize: function (){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function (){
        console.log('called');
        var template = Handlebars.compile($('#contact-list-item').html());
        this.el.html(template(this.model));
    }
});
```

when I navigate to the page the console logs "ContactListView init" but does not output "Rendering all items in the contact list". why is this?

Comment: I suspect `_(this.collection.models)` has something to do with it as this appears to be invalid syntax. Perhaps you means to use straight braces? `_[this.collections.models]`

Comment: where is the code that tries to render a `ContactListView`? Are you sure it's being instantiated and rendered?

Comment: Did my answer help? If so can you mark it as the correct one? If not, can you clarify where you still have questions?

Answer (score 0):

if `this.collection` is a `Backbone.Collection` object, then you should use

```
this.collection.each(function (contact) {
  // work here
});
```

Your render function will look something like this ([inspired by the LayoutManager docs](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Nested-views#wiki-using-views-object-1)):

```
beforeRender: function (){
    console.log('Rendering all items in the contact list');
    var self = this;
    this.collection.each(function (contact) {
        var contactlistitem = new ContactListItemView({model: contact});
        self.insertView(contactlistitem);
    });
}
```

Somewhere else in your code, perhaps in a controller or the router, you will need code like this to create the collection layout:

```
// Create an instance of the list view.
var layout = new ContactListView();

// Insert into the Document.
layout.$el.appendTo("body");

// Render the View with the contacts collection.
layout.render({ collection: myCollection });
```